# Why is using let resulting in undefined in a block of code?

Tags: ecmascript-6

When running code in a code block it results in 'undefined' then using the 'this' to reference a local variable in a block of code.

The strange thing is when removing the 'this' keyword in the same block, it prints fine.

```js
let productId = 12;

if (true) {
    let productId = 10
    console.log(this.productId) // results in 'undefined'
    console.log(this) //results in '{}'
    console.log(productId) // results in '10'
}
```

Was under the impression that the 'this.productId' would refer directly to the productId in the true code block.

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with the block of code you're in.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: @tkausl — `this` is `window` in the block of code, and if `let` was `var` a property would be created on the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

> 'this' to reference a local variable in a block of code.

That **never** happens. It just *looks* that way if "local" and "global" happen to be the same.

Here you can see how it behaves when you use `var` in a global scope.

```js
var foo = "global";

function myFunction () {
    var foo = "local";
    console.log(this.foo);
}

myFunction();
```

And here in strict mode:

```js
"use strict";
var foo = "global";

function myFunction () {
    var foo = "local";
    console.log(this.foo);
}

myFunction();
```

---

The side-effect of using `var` in the global scope creating a `window` property of the same name is weird and confusing.

When `let` was created it wasn't designed to use the same weird and confusing behaviour.

`this` being `window` by default is also weird and confusing, and isn't the case in Strict mode.

Comment: Much thanks, did a little more testing using the following change in the code.  By adding the this.id= 'foo' to the code in my question, the second console.log(this), did show that '{id: 'foo'}' it's reference.